# How to replace string with variable in jQuery selector for usisng attributes values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

How do I use a variable to replace the value of the id selector string in jQuery?

For example, I can return the correct answer using the actual string "1325":

```
var textAddForm = jQuery(".ms-itmHoverEnabled[id*='1325']").find( "div" ).attr
("title");
```

but how would I use a variable value to replace the function of '1325' using jquery?

This doesn't work of course:

```
var val = 1325;
var textAddForm = jQuery(".ms-itmHoverEnabled[id*=val]").find( "div" ).attr("title");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. All you have to do is edit the string parameter you pass to your `jQuery()` function, making sure your `val` variable gets in there somehow.

Some examples are:

```
var val = 1325;
var textAddForm = jQuery(".ms-itmHoverEnabled[id*=" + val + "]").find( "div" ).attr("title");
```

or (using the ` character instead of quotes):

```
var val = 1325;
var textAddForm = jQuery(`.ms-itmHoverEnabled[id*=${val}]`).find( "div" ).attr("title");
```

or (prepare the selector string before using it):

```
var val = 1325;
var selector = ".ms-itmHoverEnabled[id*=" + val + "]";
var textAddForm = jQuery(selector).find( "div" ).attr("title");
```